# What's the replacement for jwt.key-uri in spring boot 2

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

We are using spring boot 1 oauth with following properties.

security.oauth2.resource.jwt.key-uri

Somehow it was missing from spring boot2, any replacement for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked the same question in the [gitter chat](https://gitter.im/spring-projects/spring-boot).

Dave Syer said:

> Those features were removed. They are migrating to Spring Security.
>   But slowly. The plan is to have a shim jar that you can use in the
>   transition period. but that's not done yet @rwinch said he was going
>   to publish something after Spring One (i.e. next week earliest)

So there is no replacement yet. They removed some resource server Autoconfiguration from spring-boot. And they did not yet add it back to spring-security. But this will come soon.

So all you can do at the moment is to copy over the needed code from spring-boot 1.5.

[image]

**EDIT**

In the meantime there is a project that helps you to get the spring-security-oauth autoconfiguration in spring-boot 2 - see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth2-boot

See also the spring boot 1.5->2.0 migration guide - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#oauth2

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, and after searching a lot of resources on internet I came to this solution:

There's a **JwkTokenStore** (which is different from a JwtTokenStore). This JwkTokenStore accepts a string in the constructor which points to a key-set-url.

So I ended up with this in my ResourceServer config:

```
@Value("${security.oauth2.resource.jwk.key-set-uri}")
private String keySetUri;

@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
   JwkTokenStore jwkTokenStore = new JwkTokenStore(keySetUri, accessTokenConverter());
   return jwkTokenStore;
}

@Bean
public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
   JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
   return converter;
}
```

I'm using this with Azure AD/OpenIDConnect and for us it works fine.

Kind regards,

Danny

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with the same thing when migrating from spring boot 1 to 2. For the moment, you can keep your oauth2 properties exactly the same. I just added a method using WebClient for retrieving the public key :

```
    private String getPublicKeyValue(String uriKey) {
    return Optional.of(WebClient.create(publicKeyUri))
                   .map(j -> j.get().retrieve().bodyToMono(JwtObject.class))
                   .map(Mono::block)
                   .map(JwtObject::getValue)
                   .orElseThrow(
                           () -> new RuntimeException("An error has occured while getting the public key from remote : " + publicKeyUri));
}
```

while publicKeyUri is :

```
@Value("${security.oauth2.resource.jwk.key-set-uri}")
private String publicKeyUri;
```

And use it like :

```
   @Bean
public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
    JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    converter.setVerifierKey(getPublicKeyValue(publicKeyUri));
    return converter;
}
```

You can also configure the public key value directly rather than the URI which is much more simpler.

Of course, this is just a temporary solution until spring boot 2 comes with the real feature.